# Arrange RelativeLayout below another dynamically

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to dynamically build relative layouts consisting of an image and a textview at the moment. I have tried building a loop to place the next relative layout below the former one, but I can't really make it work. The end result should be something like this, but I guess that if i figure out how to align below the former one, I can also figure out how to place it right_of the former relative layout. 
[image]

Any suggestions? This is my code so far:

```
RelativeLayout container1 = (RelativeLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
            RelativeLayout tile = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
            tile.setId(i);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.height = height / 3;
            params.width = width / 2;
            tile.setLayoutParams(params);

            ImageButton ibGood = new ImageButton(getActivity());
            ibGood.setId(1);
            ibGood.setImageResource(pictures.get(0));
            ibGood.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            ibGood.setMaxHeight(height / 3 / 5 * 4);
            ibGood.setMaxWidth(width);
            ibGood.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            ibGood.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            tile.addView(ibGood);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tvPriceParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            tvPriceParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ibGood.getId());
            tvPriceParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, ibGood.getId());

            TextView tvPrice = new TextView(getActivity());
            tvPrice.setId(2);
            tvPrice.setHeight(tile.getHeight() / 5);
            tvPrice.setWidth(tile.getWidth() / 5 * 2);
            tvPrice.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
            tvPrice.setText(Integer.toString(price.get(0)));
            tile.addView(tvPrice, tvPriceParam);

            if (counter == 0) {
                container1.addView(tile);
            } else if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, -1);
                tile.setLayoutParams(lay);
                container1.addView(tile);
            }

            counter += 1;
        }
```

Comment: Don't set an Id like that. `tvPrice.setId(2);`. View id's must be unique. Use `View.generateViewId()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make it with the custom gridview !! why you are doing this with the relative layout ?

here is the link which you can use to achieve what do you want..

http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/09/android-custom-gridview-example.html

http://www.caveofprogramming.com/uncategorized/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android/

please visit 3 links are there you will get that you want .. with relative layout ..

Thanks,
Madhav

Comment: Thank you for that input, had to do some tweaking to make it work with Fragments. I actually looked at GridView, but somehow i got the understanding that i couldn't add anything else than pictures to the grid.

Comment: You can add textview small images and much more with custom grid view , you can also arrange the grid view items with 2 or 3 items per row. and also you can put overate the image by one small semitransparent image on the image view and put your text and another images are on that gird items.

Comment: FYI , 

You can also use below link as a custom grid ,
http://techiedreams.com/android-custom-gridview-scalable-auto-adjusting-col-width/

Please have a look.